# Como reordenar uma lista usando PHP?

Tags: php

Bom, boa noite pessoal, quero deixar claro aqui que não sou um programador profissional ou algo do tipo, apenas pego alguns bicos que surgem e, especificamente nesse, eu agarrei de vez...

O conhecimento que tenho de php é básico (eu acho) e isso não tá me permitindo resolver o seguinte problema:

Tenho essa primeira lista aqui:

```
05:50 AUDJPY CALL
06:00 EURCHF PUT
08:25 GBPAUD PUT
08:40 USDJPY PUT
10:05 GBPJPY CALL
```

E ela tem que "se reordenar" pra isso:

```
AUDJPY 05:50 CALL
EURCHF 06:00 PUT
GBPAUD 08:25 PUT
USDJPY 08:40 PUT
GBPJPY 10:05 CALL
```

Então basicamente basta "inverter" a posição da hora com o par de moeda

Como não conheço muito de php, acabei descobrindo várias funções presentes na linguagem, porém nenhuma delas me ajudou (coisas tipo explode, implode e wordwrap) e também tentei várias outras alternativas possíveis, mas nenhuma eu tive exito.

Meu trabalho é fazer um código em que:

O cliente entra com a lista 1(em sua forma) e é retornado para ele a lista 2(reordenada)

Qualquer ajuda será muuuito bem vinda, já estou louco aqui e não consigo pensar em mais nada

Segue abaixo um 'progresso' bem inútil que eu fiz, usei a função wordwrap para quebrar o espaçamento de alguns caracteres da lista, ficou até mais organizado do que a lista original, porém ainda não é o que preciso...

```
 <?php


       $lista = "    

05:50 AUDJPY CALL
06:00 EURCHF PUT
08:25 GBPAUD PUT
08:40 USDJPY PUT
10:05 GBPJPY CALL   ";



      $newtext = wordwrap($lista, 15, "<br />");

      echo "$newtext" ; 

      ?>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a transição da lista 1 para 2. Você quer ordenar a lista 1 com base no horário?

Comment: Lucas Pace, eu quero apenas pegar o elemento "par de moeda" (que seria o USDJPY e joga-lo para frente, já que na lista que o cliente vai fornecer, ele está no meio. Se não tiver entendido eu posso explicar denovo kkk

Comment: Augusto Vasques, existe no php alguma função que eu possa meio que "selecionar a partir de uma string até um limite e jogar essa string para outra posição então?

Comment: Ah, Lucas Pace, acho que entendi o que quer dizer, não, horário não tem importancia de ordem ali... apenas quero mudar a posição mesmo

Comment: Nossa, Perdão Augusto, eu inseri a lista 2 errada, acabei de corrigir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que quebrar a string em seus componentes para então poder os reagrupar.

Comece limpando a extremidades da entrada removendo os espaços iniciais e finais com [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php).
Depois separe o texto em linhas usando [`expode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php).
Para cada linha obtida novamente use `expode()`, desta vez para separar a linha nos valores.
Troque as colunas de posição e então usando [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) reagrupe os valores em uma nova linha.
Termine com `implode()` formando um nova string.

```
<?php

$lista = "    

05:50 AUDJPY CALL
06:00 EURCHF PUT
08:25 GBPAUD PUT
08:40 USDJPY PUT
10:05 GBPJPY CALL   ";

$lista = trim($lista);            // Tira os espaços das extremidades.
$linhas = explode("\n", $lista);  // Quebra a string em linhas.

//Para cada linha obtida por referência(&)...
foreach($linhas as &$linha){
  $aux = explode(" ", $linha);                       //Quebra as linhas em colunas.
  $linha = implode(" ",[$aux[1],$aux[0],$aux[2]]);   //Troca a posição das colunas e substitui a linha.
}


echo implode("\n",$linhas); // Reagrupa as linhas em uma string.
```

Resultado:

```
AUDJPY 05:50 CALL
EURCHF 06:00 PUT
GBPAUD 08:25 PUT
USDJPY 08:40 PUT
GBPJPY 10:05 CALL
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/SwapStringColumn)

O que não difere muito dum mesmo exemplo utilizando [`str_getcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-getcsv.php) ao invés de explode.

```
<?php

$lista = "    

05:50 AUDJPY CALL
06:00 EURCHF PUT
08:25 GBPAUD PUT
08:40 USDJPY PUT
10:05 GBPJPY CALL   ";

$lista = trim($lista);
$linhas = str_getcsv($lista,"\n");

foreach($linhas as &$linha){
  $aux = str_getcsv($linha," ");
  $linha = implode(" ",[$aux[1],$aux[0],$aux[2]]); 
}

echo implode("\n",$linhas);
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/CSVSwapStrigColumns)

Comment: cara, eu não sei como te agradecer por isso, você é um anjo enviado por jesus e eu tenho certeza kkkkkk. Cara, eu nunca ia descobrir isso, pode ter certeza que agora a partir disso eu vou conseguir basear meu projeto em muitas coisas, meus sinceros obrigados!!!!!!